# Sharing types across F# .fsx files

Tags: f#

Is there a way to share types across fsx files?

When using #load to load the same file containing a type from multiple FSX files they seem to be prefixed into a different FS_00xx namespace each time, which means you can't pass them around.

Are there any ways around this behaviour without resorting to compiling into an assembly?

Comment: Maybe having modules in `.fs` files?

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis already tried various combinations of modules and namespaces - doesn't seem to have any affect - the namespaces just get prefixed with FS_00xx instead

Comment: Can you post some code where these FS_00xx namespaces appear? If I use a `.fs`-file with a namespace it works fine: http://pastebin.com/QZ2m0WUe

Comment: what about #load "MyScript.fsx" ??

Comment: Which version of F# are you using? There were issues around this in F#3.x but were fixed in F#4.

Answer (score 9):

As for

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233169.aspx

> [.fsx files are] used to include informal testing code in F# without adding the test code to your application, and without creating a separate project for it. By default, script files are not included in the build of a project even when they are part of a project.

This means that if you have a project with enough structure to be having such dependency problems, you should not use `.fsx` files, instead write modules/namespaces using `.fs` files. That is, you really should compile them types into an assembly.

The f# interactive interpreter generates assembly for each loaded files. If you load a file twice, the bytecode is generated twice, and the types are different even if they have the same definition and the same name. This means that *there is no way for you to share types between two .fsx files, unless one of them includes the other*.

When you `#load` a file which has the same types as ones already present in your environment, the f#  interactive interpreter can use two different strategy:

1. refuse to load the file if conflicts with existing names arises (complaining that some stuff is already defined)
2. put the names in `FS_00xx` namespace (so that they are actually different types from the ones you already loaded), eventually `open`ing the resulting namespace so that names are available from interactive session.

Since *fsx files are supposed to be used as informal test* it is more user-friendly to use the second approach (there are also technical reason for which the second approach is used, mainly dependent on `.net` VM type system, and the fact that existing types cannot be changed at runtime).

Answer (score 9):

[**Note:** This is a more specific answer to a [more specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399576/conflicting-versions-of-same-type) that is a duplicate of this one.]

I don't think there is a nice and easy solution for this. The one solution I have been using in some projects (like [the F# snippets web site](https://github.com/fssnippets)) is to have only one top-level `fsx` file that loads a number of `fs` files. For example, see [app.fsx](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/app.fsx).

So, you would have `common.fs`, `intMapper.fs` and `stringMapper.fs` that would be loaded from `caller.fsx` as follows:

```
#load "common.fs"
#load "stringMapper.fs"
#load "intMapper.fs"
open Common
```

Inside `stringMapper.fs` and `intMapper.fs`, you do *not* load `common.fs`. The common types will be loaded by `caller.fsx` before, so things will work.

The only issue with this is that `intMapper.fs` now isn't a standalone script file - and if you want to get autocomplete in an editor, you need to add a `fsproj` file that specifies the file order. In F# snippets project, there is [a project file](https://github.com/fssnippets/fssnip-website/blob/master/FsSnip.WebSite.fsproj) which specifies the order in whch the editor should see and load the files.

Comment: I can't believe I'm thinking about include guards in F#!

Answer (score 2):

Have all the `#load` and `#open` directives in the file you actually run from fsi.exe (C in the example below), and make sure the loaded files themselves do not `#load` their own dependencies:

Files A.fsx, B.fsx, C.fsx. B depends on A. C depends on B and A.

B contains

```
//adding the code below would cause the types defined in A to be loaded twice
//#load "A.fsx"
//#open A
```

C contains

```
#load "A.fsx"
#open A
#load "B.fsx"
#open B
```

Unfortunately this then makes all the files hard to edit from Visual Studio - the editor doesn't know about their dependencies and shows all sorts of errors.

Therefore this is a bit of a hack, and the recommended way seems to be to have a single .fsx file and compile everything else into a .dll :

> ```
> // file1.fsx
> #r "MyAssembly.dll"
> ```
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx

Comment: is this another question or a comment? It seems not to be an answer (or is it?)

Comment: just in case it's another question: you should ask it in your own - but to help you out a bit: .fsx are supposed to be single-files - if you want a project structure with multiple files depending on each other you should ... well .. make an project and use .fs files (see the *answer* pqnet gave above)

Comment: @Carsten I have edited the answer to make it look more like an answer (yes, I was initially going to ask a new question but after SO helpfully suggested this similar question, I found my own solution)

Comment: @Carsten I have added a note about having a single .fsx file as you suggested. But there is no need to put everything into a project.