# Conflicting versions of same type

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have the following `F#` script files:

**common.fsx**

```
type CommonRecord = { Name : string }
```

**intMapper.fsx**

```
#load "common.fsx"
open Common

let toInt payload = payload.Name.Length
```

**stringMapper.fsx**

```
#load "common.fsx"
open Common

let toString payload = payload.Name
```

**caller.fsx**

```
#load "stringMapper.fsx"
#load "intMapper.fsx"
open Common

let a = { Name = "Hello " }
let str : string = StringMapper.toString a
let i : int = IntMapper.toInt a
```

When I try to run caller.fsx in F# Interactive I get the following compiler error:

```
caller.fsx(8,42): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
FSI_0037.Common.CommonRecord    
but here has type
FSI_0038.Common.CommonRecord
```

I'm guessing this is because when I load each of stringMapper.fsx and intMapper.fsx I load distinct instances of common.fsx, which the compiler then gets confused by.

Is there a recommended way to achieve what I am trying to do? i.e. Dependency tree in my script files that isn't "totally ordered"?

**WORKAROUND**

As mentioned by Chad - this can't be done.  The work around I used was to compile my common script as a dll:

```
fsc.exe --target:library Common.fsx
```

and then reference this in the scripts using `#r Common.dll`.

Comment: The short answer is, you can't. You'll have to put shared types in a single assembly since F# scripts are compiled to their own assembly.

Comment: Well, this is silly. I just wrote an answer to this question while it was closed. I posted it to the other question, but that's a bit stupid, because I refer to the example from the OP. So here is my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24285116/sharing-types-across-f-fsx-files/38399973#38399973